# Native Java support for JSON?

Tags: java, json

Is there native support for JSON in Java or is it through 3rd party libraries only?  Most tutorials I've seen use external libraries but was wondering if something had been added in later versions of Java.

Comment: There's nothing in core Java (to my knowledge).